# Отмена изменения имени у TreeNode

Tags: java, jtree

Есть программа, имеющая в себе дерево. Я бы хотел сделать так, чтобы изменение имени ноды по двойному клику происходило только при выполнении определённого условия. Сейчас у меня происходит так:

```
class TreeElement{
    private String name;
    private String type;
    ...Some basic methods...
}
class EntryEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private TreeElement entry;
    private JTextField box;
    public EntryEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        box = ((JTextField) editorComponent);
    }
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(final JTree tree, final Object value,                                                   final boolean isSelected, final boolean expanded, final boolean leaf, final int row) {
        entry = (TreeElement) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (some condition) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not done");
            return box;
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!");
            box.setText(box.getName());
        }
       return box;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        entry.setName(box.getText());
        return entry;
    }
}
```

Но при этом всё равно после окошка появляется поле ввода, и значение можно изменить. Как это исправить? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно переопределить метод `JTree.isPathEditable`:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "Root" );
root.add( new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "Child1" ) );
root.add( new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "Child2" ) );

TreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

JTree tree = new JTree( model ) {
    @Override
    public boolean isPathEditable( TreePath path ) {
        if (!super.isPathEditable( path )) return false;

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();
        Object entry = node.getUserObject();

        if ( entry.equals( "Child1" ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

Либо можно переопределить `DefaultCellEditor.isCellEditable`:

```
class EntryEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    /* ... */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(java.util.EventObject anEvent) {
        if ( anEvent instanceof MouseEvent ) {
            JTree t = (JTree)anEvent.getSource();
            MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent)anEvent;

            TreePath path = t.getPathForLocation( e.getX(), e.getY() );

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();
            Object entry = node.getUserObject();

            if ( e.getClickCount() >= 2 ) {
                if ( entry.equals( "Child1" ) ) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.isCellEditable( anEvent );
    };
    /* ... */
}
```